# Getting id of PHP 8 Socket

Tags: php, sockets, php-8

With the new socket instance returning from socket_create() in php 8, **how do we get a numeric or unique reference to this socket in the way casting to int would work in earlier versions**. This is used for many things, including connection tracking in log files and storing metadata about connections when they are passed into/return from socket_select().

**Before php 8:**

```
$socket_resource = socket_create(...);
$socket_id = (int)$socket_resource;
```

**After php 8**

```
$socket_instance = socket_create(...);
$socket_id = (int)$socket_instance; // PHP Warning:  Object of class Socket could not be converted to int
```

There is a new function in php 8 `get_resource_id($resource)` which looks the same as casting to int, but this does not work on sockets.

Comment: As of PHP8, [socket_create()](https://www.php.net/socket_create) doesn't return a resource, but a [Socket](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.socket.php). _"A fully opaque class which replaces Socket resources as of PHP 8.0.0."_

Comment: See also [PHP 8.0: Sockets extension resources (Socket and AddressInfo) are class objects](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/sockets-sockets-addressinfo).

Comment: Yes, it returns a socket now, but there is no function get_socket_id($socket) and I can't find a way of getting an identifier back from the socket instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [spl_object_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-id.php) with any object. It's an arbitrary value that can be reused, but so are resource IDs.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Because spl_object_id() does not work with a resource, to make it work with earlier versions of PHP it's neccessary to do something like this: $id = ($s instanceof \Socket ? spl_object_id($s) : (int)$s);

Comment: @Drewster You also have `is_resource()`.

Comment: Do you think that is_resource() would be better than instanceof?

Comment: No idea. I'd say performance differences are probably negligible (probably!) and it's all about what semantics you prefer.